# How to create custom URL's for each record with a php dynamic page?

Tags: php, dynamic-pages

I have a lot of titles and details in the database, and I don't want to create a file for each record, but I want to create a dynamic page with different URL that will display the details with a link to that dynamic page.

For example, when user click on a link like:
 href="./sports/football"

the dynamic page shows the details in following URL:
./sports/football.php

NOTE: I don't want the URL address to be like the following:
./sports?search=football;

Comment: Go read up on _URL rewriting_ … (This gets asked about all the time, and there are plenty of explanations how it works available on the net.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok you do this:

1. https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php
2. Copy your desired URL and paste inside 1.)
3. put `sports/` at `Prefix` tab
4. select empty box in `Suffix` tab
5. And you'll get

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^sports/([^/]*)$ /sports.php?search=$1 [L]
> ```

6. create file named `.htaccess` and paste 5.) inside and save
7. Try open your link again and it will be like http://www.myurl.com/sports/football